# Accessing class methods from another class in Python 2.7

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, tkinter

I am writing a Tkinter GUI for an assignment and have come to have some problems with accessing class methods. The first bit of code I've pasted in here is the top-level interface class. The main function of the code creates an instance of this class where "master" is and instance of Tk().

```
class PlotApp(object):
    """
    Top level interface. Contains canvas and other widgets.
    """

    def __init__(self, master):

        # Initialise variables, world screen class and window features
        master.wm_minsize(740, 480)
        master.configure(bg = "gray80")
        self.isFunctionDrawn = False           

        # Create objects
        self.pointf = PointFrame(master)
        self.canvas = Canvas(master, bg = "white", bd = 2, relief = SUNKEN,
                             highlightbackground = "gray80")
        self.canvas.pack(expand = True, fill = BOTH, padx = 10, side = TOP)
        self.functionf = FunctionFrame(master)
        self.plotf = PlotFrame(master)
        self.buttonf = ButtonFrame(master, self.canvas)
```

`self.functionf` is an instance of my `FunctionFrame` class, which contains a method called `getFunction()`. I want a button in the `ButtonFrame` class instance to access this method, but I don't know how to do this. I've tried:

```
def testFunction(self):
    self.parent.functionf.getFunction()
```

(where `parent` is the `master` argument in the first bit of code) but this seems to be calling `functionf` as an object of `Tk()`, which obviously isn't going to work. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

master is your Tk() instance. just because you called the variable `parent` in your ButtonFrame class doesn't mean it's the object that created the instance.

You need to either pass in `self` from `PlotApp` as parent (and if you need your `master` object in your ButtonFrame, save master in something like `self.master` in `PlotApp`), or you need to also pass in your `PlotApp` instance's `self` variable to your `ButtonFrame`.